# XSL - transform array elements into a list of independent elements with element_name+index names

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, transformation

I have very basic knowledge of XSL transformation. 
I need to convert an array into a list of independent elements like so:

input:

```
<Fields>
    <Field>
         <Name>One</Name>
         <Value>1</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Two</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Three</Name>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Four</Name>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Field>
    </Fields>
```

Desired output:

```
<Fields>
     <Field1>
            <Name>One</Name>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </Field1>
        <Field2>
            <Name>Two</Name>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </Field2>
        <Field3>
            <Name>Three</Name>
            <Value>3</Value>
        </Field3>
        <Field4>
            <Name>Four</Name>
            <Value>4</Value>
        </Field4>
</Fields>
```

Is it feasible at all? 
Appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Feasible, yes. However, you should think twice before going there, because while the change creates no advantage that I can see, it will make the result significantly more difficult to process than the original. -- Note also that your output is missing a root element, which every XML document must have.

Comment: The output is not valid XML as it has multiple root elements.

Comment: Also, are the elements in your XML actually called "Field" or were you looking for a more generic solution?

Comment: Sorry for missing root element, sure it should have one. It is not production xml, just an artificial sample to illustrate the problem.  The real reason behind this question is that consumer's software cannot map fields if their names are not represented by static xml nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> The real reason behind this question is that consumer's software
>   cannot map fields if their names are not represented by static xml
>   nodes.

I am not sure what exactly that means, but if you are sure that's the result you want, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="Field{position()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. I also found another similar solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190322/xsl-name-value-pair-transformation?rq=1 . It translates <Field> elements to corresponding {Name} elements. Adopted to my problem and put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from michael.hor257k works great and answered my original question completely, but I realized that the output from this transformation just suits my needs better, providing field names are unique.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Fields>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Field" />
    </Fields>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{Name}">

     <xsl:element name="Value">
      <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Fields>
    <One>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </One>
    <Two>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Two>
    <Three>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </Three>
    <Four>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Four>
</Fields>
```